# Resetting Rail Migrations to Match Database Schema

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, migration, rake, database-schema

In my rails app, I had started out completing migrations using the typical `rails g ...` followed by `rake db:migrate`. However, upon moving from Postgres to MySQL, I began creating tables with PHPMyAdmin instead of migrations and rake command.

Now if do use migrations and rake, it will deploy an older db schema. How can I "reset" my apps db schema to match the up to date databases schema so I can continue forward using `rake db:migrate`?

Comment: Is it `rake db:schema:dump` you're looking for? That won't create individual migrations to fill the gaps, but will create `schema.rb` according to the current MySQL schema.

Comment: `Now if do use migrations and rake, it will deploy an older db schema.` => Not so sure about this. When there are tables in the database that are not part of the `db/schema.rb` the `db/schema.rb` gets updated with the tables from the database on running `rake db:migrate`.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yes, that was the proper command